# Helper Method in RSpec Not Allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. I have a helper method called `helper_method` which is just running a SQL query to grab some data. This data is used to determine if my response error returns correctly. `sanitize_and_execute` is just a wrapper around a call to `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`.

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Db # a module where sanitize_and_execute comes from

define MyModel do
  let...
  let...
  def helper_method(vendor_id)
    query = <<~SQL.squish
      select distinct thing1, thing2
       from thing
       where id = (?)
    SQL
    sanitize_and_execute([query, id])
  end

  context 'some context' do
    let(:my_model) { create(:my_model) }

    it 'returns the correct error' do
      expect(response.error).to include "error: #{helper_method(my_model.id)}"
    end
  end

end
```

This leads to the error `'sanitize_and_execute' is not available from within an example (e.g. an 'it' block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. 'before', 'let', etc).` What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: There are many things in RSpec that are contextual, and defining a method in that context but calling it in the wrong context doesn't change that restriction.

Comment: @tadman yeah i see that but I'm unsure of how to fix the context issue in this situation.

Comment: What is `Db` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'spec_helper'
define MyModel do
  # Include into context of the example
  include Db # a module where sanitize_and_execute comes from
  # ...

  # But why not just use a model instead? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  def helper_method(vendor_id)
    query = Arel::Table.new('thing').then do |tbl|
      tbl.project(tbl[:thing1], , tbl[:thing1])
         .distinct
         .where(tbl[:id]).eq(vendor_id)
    end
    sanitize_and_execute(query.to_sql)
  end
end
```